# Convert python dictionary to uppercase

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary, file-io

For some reason my code refuses to convert to uppercase and I cant figure out why. Im trying to then write the dictionary to a file with the uppercase dictionary values being inputted into a sort of template file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
from collections import Counter


#take every word from a file and put into dictionary
newDict = {}
dict2 = {}
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            k,v = line.strip().split(' ')
            newDict[k.strip()] = v.strip()
print(newDict)
choice = input('Enter 1 for all uppercase keys or 2 for all lowercase, 3 for capitalized case or 0 for unchanged \n')
print("Your choice was " + choice)

if choice == 1:
    for k,v in newDict.items():
        newDict.update({k.upper(): v.upper()})
if choice == 2:
    for k,v in newDict.items():
        dict2.update({k.lower(): v})


#find keys and replace with word

print(newDict)
with open("tester.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("outwords.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('{PETNAME}', str(newDict['PETNAME:'])))
            fout.write(line.replace('{ACTIVITY}', str(newDict['ACTIVITY:'])))

myfile = open("outwords.txt")
txt = myfile.read()
print(txt)
myfile.close()
```

Comment: let me guess: you're getting "dictionary changes during iteration" ?

Answer (score 22):

In python 3 you cannot do that:

```
for k,v in newDict.items():
    newDict.update({k.upper(): v.upper()})
```

because it changes the dictionary while iterating over it and python doesn't allow that (It doesn't happen with python 2 because `items()` used to return a *copy* of the elements as a `list`). Besides, even if it worked, it would keep the old keys (also: it's very slow to create a dictionary at each iteration...)

Instead, rebuild your dict in a dict comprehension:

```
newDict = {k.upper():v.upper() for k,v in newDict.items()}
```

Comment: Why `newDict}` is not sufficient? I tried your solution and it of course works but I'm just curious why version without `.items()` doesn't work.

Comment: because with just `newDict` the loop iterates on the keys, not the key/value tuples

Comment: Okay, so I guess it's because `myDict.keys()` is only for keys, `myDict.values()` is only for values and `myDict.items()` is for key/value tuples?

By the way - is it possible to uppercase dictionary keys without looping?

Comment: @Konrad exactly. `.keys()` is really not super useful as iterating/testing on `myDict` has the same effect. For "is it possible to uppercase dictionary keys without looping?" => you have to apply upper() on each key so the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

You should not change dictionary items as you iterate over them. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) state:

> Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may
>   raise a `RuntimeError` or fail to iterate over all entries.

One way to update your dictionary as required is to pop values and reassign in a `for` loop. For example:

```
d = {'abc': 'xyz', 'def': 'uvw', 'ghi': 'rst'}

for k, v in d.items():
    d[k.upper()] = d.pop(k).upper()

print(d)

{'ABC': 'XYZ', 'DEF': 'UVW', 'GHI': 'RST'}
```

An alternative is a dictionary comprehension, as [shown by @Jean-FrançoisFabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004357/9209546).